# Is there a way to include max() in a method for arrays as well as floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define a method such that method(input) return the max(input,0) per value of input.
"input" can be a float or an n-dimensional array.

I tried my best with np.maximum, np.amax, np.max and slices and loops, but couldn't get it to work.

My (not working) code:

```
def function(input):
    return np.maximum(input,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
arr = np.random.normal(0, 1, 5)
print(arr)
```

```
[-0.23415337 -0.23413696  1.57921282  0.76743473 -0.46947439]
```

Use this function:

```
def function(input):
    return [np.maximum(i,0) for i in input]

function(arr)
```

```
Out[42]: [0.0, 0.0, 1.5792128155073915, 0.7674347291529088, 0.0]
```

The logic of the function is: for element in input, return max(0, element)